# comparing 2 columns of a dataset row by row and getting a 3th column with answers

Tags: r, statistics

I'm totally new in R and faced a following problem to sort:

I have a data "mydata" with 2 columns, column A and column B :

```
col1 col2
F    M
F    M
F    M
F    M
M    M
M    F
F    F
F    F
F    M
F    M
F    F
M    F
M    M
M    M
F    M
```

and a final result I need to get is some like :

```
col1    col2    match
F       M       FALSE
F       M       FALSE
F       M       FALSE
F       M       FALSE
M       M       TRUE
M       F       FALSE
F       F       TRUE
F       F       TRUE
F       M       FALSE
F       M       FALSE
F       F       TRUE
M       F       FALSE
M       M       TRUE
M       M       TRUE
F       M       FALSE
```

Comment: Please format your data properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `==` to get the logical index

```
df1$match <- df1[,1]==df1[,2]
df1
#   col1 col2 match
#1     F    M FALSE
#2     F    M FALSE
#3     F    M FALSE
#4     F    M FALSE
#5     M    M  TRUE
#6     M    F FALSE
#7     F    F  TRUE
#8     F    F  TRUE
#9     F    M FALSE
#10    F    M FALSE
#11    F    F  TRUE
#12    M    F FALSE
#13    M    M  TRUE
#14    M    M  TRUE
#15    F    M FALSE
```

Comment: I may doing something wrong, but with this solution getting and error :  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: @eadmineadmin  This solution was based on the example you showed.  It showed that the dataset have two columns.  If you have factor columns, try `as.character(df1[,1])==as.character(df1[,2])`

Comment: Perfect solution , Thanks Akrun

Comment: yeah,  as.character(df1[,1])==as.character(df1[,2])       this one worked perfect

Answer (score 2):

I am having trouble reading your question based on the lack of formatting, but I think this is what you want.

```
df$match=ifelse(df$A == df$B, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: ifelse is redundant as `==` will return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: Good point, I suppose if the OP wanted some other type of flag for the matches, such as a custom string, ifelse could be appropriate. In this case though, akrun's answer is more efficient.

Comment: Hi Justin , It works as a charm , Thank you !  Just one more thing, It seems In column B I have some values from a new type format not which are not present in column A, so I'm getting an error: " level sets of factors are different"  is there any way to avoid this ?  Thanks